# do_action to meta data when post is published to change meta data of other post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Post type default wordpress 'post'
Other Custom post type 'series'
and Series name is same as category used in post.
i want to update or add (if not exist) meta date of series post when default post is published? (series post == default post category name)

my code

```
add_action('publish_post', 'create_asim_update_series_date_pub');
function create_asim_update_series_date_pub($post_id) {
    $upcoming_episode_value = get_post_meta($post_id,'upcoming_episode',true);
    if ($upcoming_episode_value=="No") {
$category_details=get_the_category($post_id);
$my_category_name ='';
foreach($category_details as $category_detail){
$my_category_name = $category_detail->cat_name;
}
$my_series_detail = get_page_by_title($my_category_name, OBJECT, 'series'); 
$my_series_id = $my_series_detail->ID;  
$asim_update_time_id = update_post_meta( $my_series_id, 'asim_update_date', date('YmdHis') );
$asim_update_time_id = update_post_meta( $my_series_id, 'asim_update_time', date('YmdHis') );
}   
}
```

upcoming_episode --- is meta data create with ACF to check if change should be done or not?

this coding is working when i update any post but when i publish new post it doesn't work.?
can anyone point out why is it happening? Thanks a lot

Comment: You should try add_post_meta and update_post_meta both

Comment: i have try but does work for me. by add extra
add_action('save_post', 'create_asim_update_series_date_pub');
solves my problem but why? it doesn't work for me i don't know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use add/update both post meta like this:

```
  $get_asim__date_id = get_post_meta($my_series_id, 'asim_update_date', true); 
  $get_asim__time_id = get_post_meta($my_series_id, 'asim_update_time', true); 

  if($get_asim__date_id){
      $asim_update_time_id = update_post_meta( $my_series_id, 'asim_update_date', date('YmdHis') );
  }else{
      $asim_update_time_id = add_post_meta( $my_series_id, 'asim_update_date', date('YmdHis') );
  }

  if($get_asim__time_id ){
     $asim_update_time_id = update_post_meta( $my_series_id, 'asim_update_time', date('YmdHis') );
  }else{
     $asim_update_time_id = add_post_meta( $my_series_id, 'asim_update_time', date('YmdHis') );
  }
```